# Does perfino supports REST (JAX-RS) calls

Tags: java, perfino

I am evaluating perfino in the moment.
We have multiple servers in our system that communicate with REST (JAX-RS).
The Question is: "Can perfino trace REST calls between our own servers as one transaction?"
Or does it only supports RMI and EJB...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of 3.1 there is no specific REST call tracing. We do have this in our issue tracker for a future version.